# idFTP + Connection Timeout

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

I had been trying to get a file from a ftp server, but everytime a try to connect using my code i've got the same error:

**EIdSocketError: Socket Error # 10060
Connection timed out.**

using Filezilla 3.4, I can connect and download the files, my code:

```
var
  objFTP: TidFTP;
begin
  try
    objFTP := TIdFTP.Create;
    try
      objFTP.Disconnect;
      objFTP.Host := '200.1.81.252';
      objFTP.Port := 990;
      objFTP.Username := 'user_name';
      objFTP.Password := 'user_pass';
      objFTP.Passive := True;
      objFTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(objFTP);
      objFTP.UseTLS := utUseRequireTLS;
      objFTP.TransferTimeout := 120000;
      try
        objFTP.Connect;
        objFTP.ChangeDir('/salida/acciones/2015-05-20');
        objFTP.Get('SW052015.003', 'C:\SW052015.txt');
      finally
        objFTP.Disconnect;
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(objFTP);
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
```

any suggestions?

Configurations on FileZilla:

Authentication port: 990

Data transfer port: 9080 (don't know what this is)

Encryption: Required explicit FTP over TLS

Passive mode

Force UTF-8

Comment: Have you checked your firewall settings? The fact that FileZilla is allowed to do network communication does not mean that your application is also allowed to do network communication. Many firewalls allow per application configuration.

Comment: i can't see the firewall "rules" (company policy), but using the command telnet 200.1.81.252 990 on cmd i've got connected to the server

Comment: Which line is actually raising the exception? The call to `Connect()`, `ChangeDir()`, or `Get()`? It makes a big difference. Also, you should not be calling `Disconnect()` unless `Connect()` succeeds first. Also, try using `utUseExplicitTLS` instead of `utUseRequireTLS` Also, if the server requires encryption on data transfers, you need to set the `TIdFTP.DataPortProtection` property to `ftpdpsPrivate` (by default, it is `ftpdpsClear` - no encryption).

Comment: thanks Remy, everything worked, now i can connect and get the file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I've got the code working great:

```
var
  objFTP: TidFTP;
  sCaminho: String;
begin
  sCaminho := 'C:\SW052015.txt';
  SysUtils.DeleteFile(sCaminho);
  try
    objFTP := TIdFTP.Create;
    try
      objFTP.Host := '200.1.81.252';
      objFTP.Username := 'user_name';
      objFTP.Password := 'user_pass';
      objFTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(objFTP);
      objFTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
      objFTP.DataPortProtection := ftpdpsPrivate;
      try
        objFTP.Port := 990;
        objFTP.Passive := True;
        objFTP.Connect;
        objFTP.ChangeDir('/salida/acciones/2015-05-20');
        objFTP.Get('SW052015.003', sCaminho);
      finally
        objFTP.Disconnect;
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(objFTP);
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```